# SQL equivalent on a LINQ query with ANY as a predicate

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

I have a LINQ query such as:

```
var myOffices=return table1
                .Where(o => o.department.Any());
```

`table1` has a `virtual` department property which is of type `ICollection<department>`.

I tried the below SQL but it gives me incorrect records:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 T
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM department D)
```

table1 and department are linked via a foreign key reference

please advise.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the fact that you want elements in `table1` where some `department` are **linked** to these particular `table1` element.

Suppose in `department` the foreign key for `table1` is `fk_id_table1`
and the primary key for `table1` is `id_table1` , the query should be :

```
SELECT * FROM table1 T 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM department D 
    WHERE D.fk_id_table1 = T.id_table1    -- This is the missing condition
)
```